# Array is returning empty

Tags: php, mysql

I want to retrieve the input value entered by the user and send it to the database. But for some reason it inserts a blank space in the table, instead of the value! Does someone know what's wrong?

```
<form method="post" name="name" action="pt2.php" >

<?php
//$mysql->commit();
            echo "<h3>";
            echo "Please enter the name for each seat:<br><p>&nbsp</p>";
            echo "";
            foreach($_POST['seats'] AS $seat) {
                $rowId = substr($seat, 0, 1);
                $columnId = substr($seat, 1);
        echo $rowId . $columnId . '<input type="hidden" name="seats[]" value="' . $seat . '"><input name="' . $seat . 'name" type="text"/></br>';
            }

?>

   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"><br>
</form>
```

pt2.php

```
<?php
// Connect to MySQL
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die("Connection Failed");
mysql_select_db("tickets")or die("Connection Failed");


$namei = $_POST[$seat . 'name'];

foreach ($_POST['seats'] as $seat){
echo $seat;
echo $namei;
$query = "INSERT INTO seatnames (seatname) VALUES ('$namei')";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
}
?>
```

Comment: do `echo $seat` and `echo $namei` print properly?

Comment: You are setting `$namei` before the loop instead of inside of it. `$seat` does not exist before the loop.

Comment: @Dan Grossman Exactly! Problem solved, thanks!